# Using Light - Effects of Long Exposures?

Tags: lighting, digital, long-exposure

The photo below is an example of using more light to get a movement effect of water. I know of a couple more tricks such as motion in clouds, motion with light (highway).

- Was wondering if their are others with some concept of taking a long exposure?
- How does a Long Exposure change the expression of a photo?

  - Are Long Exposures based more on time and movement than anything?

[image: Long Exposure - Representing Motion]

Comment: Can you break this down a little bit? This topic can easily fill bookshelves, and that kind of question rarely works very well here. (See the FAQ: http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: @mattdm is this a better format for the question?

Comment: This question is overly broad, and it will be difficult to select an accepted answer if one is even given. As mattdm stated, it would be best if you edited this question to narrow its scope, and asked multiple, independent questions for each specific sub topic you wish to get answers for. Explicit, direct, targeted question get explicit, direct, targeted answers. Very broad questions will generally be closed as they tend to be unanswerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few others spring to mind (sorry not to provide examples, but the web should have plenty):

- long exposures of the sea to get a glassy effect
- long exposure of the night sky for star trails
- long exposure of a monument, etc. with people passing so that they "blur out"
- intentionally changing zoom during the exposure
- second curtain flash when shooting moving objects so they are captured with a trailing blur not a leading one
- panning to capture a moving object sharply whilst blurring the background instead
- high speed photography to capture bullet impacts, balloons bursting, water droplets, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Light graffiti or whatever you want to call it.

[image]
Not the best picture in the world. I have only played with the concept. I mean really played as in I gave my cousins a bunch of colored LED key chains on the beach and just had fun.

This was done with a nikon D3000, 30s exposure, iso100.

I just googled long exposure and found [this](http://roboticsblog.org/2009/robotics-images/long-exposure-roomba-photos-are-pretty-insightful/). The path of a roomba:
[image]

[Here](http://www.buzzfeed.com/daves4/amazing-examples-of-long-exposure-photography) is a bunch of pictures too.

Comment: +1 Great examples not quite what I was looking for though thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, long exposure can also be used in night to capture the light trails of vehicles in a busy road. This is a typical night long exposure example.